# WSO2 change payload in aggregate

Tags: wso2, aggregate, clone, wso2-esb

I'm currently trying to compute a payload in an aggregate element from a sequence template. My problem is that the payload returned by this sequence is the one generated by the aggregate, not the one build with the payload factory. Here is a sample

```
<clone id="TEST" sequential="true">
  <target>
    <sequence>
       <call-template key="do-soemthing"/>
    </sequence>
  </target>
  <target>
    <sequence>
       <call-template key="do-something-else"/>
    </sequence>
  </target>
</clone>
<aggregate id="TEST">
 <completeCondition>
   <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
 </completeCondition>
 <onComplete expression="//status">
    <filter xpath="count(//status[text() = 'NOK']) = 0">
      <then>
        <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
          <format>
            <myPayload>
              <status>OK</status>
              <action>foo</action>
            </myPayload>
          </format>
          <args/>
        </payloadFactory>
      </then>
      <else>
        <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
          <format>
            <myPayload>
              <status>NOK</status>
              <action>bar</action>
            </myPayload>
          </format>
          <args/>
        </payloadFactory>
      </else>
    </filter>
  </onComplete>
</aggregate>
```

What I would expect when calling this sequence is to get back a  element but instead i get  (aggregated).
How could I solve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want mediators after clone to be executed, you must set attribute continueParent="true" on clone mediator.

But this is not enough in your case because messages generated into clone's targets are lost after clone mediator : you must move your aggregate mediator in a sequence and call this sequence inside each clone's target.

Here come a sample composed of a proxy service (that you can simply execute with your internet browser : http://localhost:8280/services/TestSOF) and a sequence used to aggregate the mock responses

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="TestSOF"
       transports="http"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="disable">
   <description/>
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2"/>
         <clone continueParent="true">
            <target>
               <sequence>
                  <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                     <format>
                        <resp1 xmlns="">
                           <status>OK</status>
                        </resp1>
                     </format>
                     <args/>
                  </payloadFactory>
                  <header name="To" action="remove"/>
                  <property name="RESPONSE" value="true"/>
                  <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
                  <sequence key="TestSOFAgg"/>
               </sequence>
            </target>
            <target>
               <sequence>
                  <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                     <format>
                        <resp2 xmlns="">
                           <status>OK</status>
                        </resp2>
                     </format>
                     <args/>
                  </payloadFactory>
                  <header name="To" action="remove"/>
                  <property name="RESPONSE" value="true"/>
                  <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
                  <sequence key="TestSOFAgg"/>
               </sequence>
            </target>
         </clone>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="DEBUG" value="after clone"/>
         </log>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="TestSOFAgg">
    <aggregate>
     <completeCondition>
       <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
     </completeCondition>
     <onComplete expression="//status">
        <log level="full"><property name="DEBUG" value="inside onComplete"/></log>
        <filter xpath="count(//status[text() = 'NOK']) = 0">
          <then>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
              <format>
                <myPayload>
                  <status>OK</status>
                  <action>foo</action>
                </myPayload>
              </format>
              <args/>
            </payloadFactory>
          </then>
          <else>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
              <format>
                <myPayload>
                  <status>NOK</status>
                  <action>bar</action>
                </myPayload>
              </format>
              <args/>
            </payloadFactory>
          </else>
        </filter>
        <respond/>
      </onComplete>
    </aggregate> 
</sequence>
```

See message logged by "after clone" : soap Body is empty (if you've used a Browser to test it, or you will have the soap message you've sent with SoapUI for exemple), your aggregate can't work here

See message logged by "inside onComplete" : you can see all the status elements inside the soap body

Modify one of the mock responses with something else that OK and try again : the response change, it works ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if I set continueParent="true" I'll not be able to get the result of the clone sequences at the end of the clone, I'll simply keep the payload from before the different call. I'll try to aggregate inside each clone element, but it doesn't sound either logic nor natural to me, as far as I always understood the aggregation should be done only once, when all the sequences are done.

Comment: wrong, aggregate mediator must be called as many times as there is reponses, this is the reason of messageCount in completeCondition : you can set -1 with clone mediator because the ESB know that 2 targets have been instanciated. When the completeCondition is true (the "last" time that aggreage mediator is called), the "onComplete" part is executed

Comment: I've done several test and I'm never getting the payload from the aggregate, I'm just retrieving the original payload. Could it be that the reason is that I'm not using this in a proxy but in a regular sequence?

Comment: Proxy's inSequence or regular sequence make no difference, it should work. Perharps does it comes from the content of your templates : share your overall config so that I can help you

Comment: An other thing to check for : the respond or send back to the client must come from inside the aggregate's onComplete, not from the initial sequence